# Solr 6 serve plugins stats in xml or json format

Tags: solr, solr4, solr6

We've just updated our solr version from 4.9 to 6.5 and we're trying to get the stats in a format that's easier to parse. For 4.9 we were accessing the plugins page to get all the stats in an xml format.

```
localhost:8080/solr/admin/plugins?stats=true
```

Is there a way to achieve this in the new version?

Answer (score 0):

Try appending &wt=xml at end of your url. 
eg : localhost:8080/solr/admin/plugins?stats=true&wt=xml

More details can be found on this page :-
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Response+Writers